Node.jsのv22.12でスクリプトが動作しない
Node.js v22.12で以下のようにファイル指定で動作させると、プロンプトに何も表示されずにプログラムが終了します。
> node test.js
(何も表示されずにプログラム終了)
test.jsの中身は何でも良いのですがconsole.log()だけでも動作しません。
console.log("Hello from Node.js");
setInterval(() => {
  console.log("Still running...");
}, 2000);



-eを使って同じコードは動作します
node -e "console.log('Hello from inline'); setInterval(()=>{console.log('Still running inline...')},3000)" 
v20.18にダウングレードすると動作します。

とりあえずは20.18にダウングレードしたので当面は問題ないのですが、22.12で起動方法について変更等ありましたでしょうか？
あるいはPC側で何か疑われる設定等ありますでしょうか？
22.12にあげる前は動作していたこと、22.12にアップグレードして動作しなくなったこと、再度20.18ダウングレードして動作できるようになった間、Node以外の設定はいじっていません。
環境はWindows環境です。

以下に同様質問 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79307167/node-js-v22-12-ends-immediately-without-any-output-when-running-a-file-on-window

Node.js v22 でこのような挙動が起こるような変更は、自分の知る限り行われていないです。
Node.js のバージョンを変えたときに何かが起こったというのが一番ありえそうです。type node でどのバイナリが実行されているか確認するなどして、きちんとバージョン更新が行えたのか確認してみてください。
